# xubuntu installation does´t get further than language selection

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, freeze, language-support, alternate

I have to install xubuntu (xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386) from a cd to a compaq evo n600c, (win xp prof, version 2002, service pack 3 preinstalled), no booting from usb possible

Mobile Intel(R) Pentium(R)
III CPU - M 1200 Mhz
789MHz -512 MB RAM

The booting from cd works and the installation menu appears. I select the language, then select "Xubuntu installation" but the screen gets black and nothing happens. (tried with english and german and it´s the same) What should I do? thanx

Comment: Some have said that it works if you don't select _anything_ on that screen, and just click next without selecting any language first (you can change it later). I've never experienced this problem myself though.

Comment: thanx but there is no "next" button, I have to select something_thx anyway